# VB.NET Change visibility of multiple labels on runtime

Tags: arrays, vb.net, label, runtime

im trying to get to change the visibility of different labels during runtime after a button click

```
    Dim labelsEmpty As New ArrayList

    Dim allTxt As New List(Of Control)
    For Each txt As TextBox In FindControlRecursive(allTxt, Me, GetType(TextBox))
        If txt.Text = "" Then
            If txt.Name = "TextBox1" Then
            Else
                'Dim textBoxName = txt.Name.ToString.Remove("txt").ToLower
                labelsEmpty.Add(txt.Name.ToString.Replace("txt", "lblMsg"))
            End If
        End If
    Next

    For Each label In labelsEmpty

        Dim Label1 As New Label
        Label1.Name = label
        Label1.Text = "Insert a value"
        Label1.Visible = True

    Next
```

This is what i have, each textbox in my form has a label used to tell the user that there was some kind of error, in this case i need to get which textbox is left empty and set the visibility of its label to true (already hidden from form start), so what i do is i go through every textbox in my form to see which one the user left empty and then take their name (ex: txtAge) and replace txt with "lblMsg" and then insert them into an array.

Doing so i get an array with all the label names that should be set to visible = true

Now i need to set their visibility and text value, so what i did is i created a for each loop and getting every label in the array, but the code i used is not working, i already checked if there are items in the array and they are there, any help? Thanks.

My Form: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrawz.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your final loop, you are creating **new** labels and never adding them to your form. If you already have existing labels on your form, you want to reference those:

```
    For Each label In labelsEmpty

        With Controls(label)
            .Text = "Insert a value"
            .Visible = True
        End With

    Next
```

Setting the Text property may be unnecessary if your labels already have the necessary text.

If you want to create new labels and then add them to your form, you need to add the control to the form after you have created it:

```
    For Each label In labelsEmpty

        Dim Label1 As New Label
        With Label1
            .Name = label
            .Text = "Insert a value"
            '.Top = 100
            '.Left = 100
            .Visible = True
        End With
        Controls.Add(Label1)

    Next
```

If you do it this way, you will need some way to set the Top and Left properties so that the labels align correctly with your existing text boxes. There are several ways to do that but I'll leave that to you as I'm fairly sure that my first solution answers your question.

Comment: The first solution is what i was looking for, however its not working since my arraylist contains strings which are the name of the labels that have to be set to visible and not the label object itself, giving me this error: "Object variable or With block variable not set"

Comment: Controls() does accept String as the argument. Are you sure that the string being passed to Controls() is the EXACT name of the label you are trying to reference?

Comment: Yes 100% Printing the first string in the array with an example with a label in the form: https://imgur.com/a/3b9YIhG

Comment: i changed the arraylist to a list of string like so: Dim labelsEmpty As New List(Of String) and now the error is "$W0 was Nothing" when doing .Text = "Insert a value". I might just trash this idea of the labels

Comment: Check that your FindControlRecursive function definitely returning the text boxes. This code definitely works: https://prnt.sc/w4u4bt

Comment: Here is the result of that code: https://prnt.sc/w4u6uk

Comment: Well i tried everything, i even removed the FindControl method and changed it with a for each that searches for every textbox in my form and it still gives me the same "Object variable or With block variable not set" error. https://imgur.com/a/VSc47DU

Comment: I am being told to move this to Chat but I don't have a high enough reputation to do that - so: you are getting the names from tabControl.TabPages(2).Controls but then trying to find them by searching on the main form. They aren't there! They are on the TabPage(2). Your second loop needs to be With tabControl.TagPages(2).Controls(label)

Comment: Dear lord, that was the problem, thank you so much for helping me and for the patience too. Leaving code for other users: https://imgur.com/a/vJGiMor

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226124/discussion-between-tod-lewis-and-nome-cognome).